# Sending PHP emails via gmail account having non gmail domain

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have been trying to send PHP emails via gmail account having non gmail domain but the email address is registered at gmail.com. The emails are not going via this account but when I give an account having @gmail.com, then the email is transmitted but it is not sending to non gmail email addresses. The code I have been using is php mailer code.

```
function smtpmailer($to, $from, $from_name, $subject, $body) {   
    global $error;  
    $mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object  
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only  
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail  
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Port = 465;   
    $mail->Username = GUSER;    
    $mail->Password = GPWD;             
    $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);  
    $mail->Subject = $subject;  
    $mail->Body = $body;  
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    if(!$mail->Send()) {  
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
        return false;  
    } else {  
        $error = 'Message sent!';  
        return true;  
    }
```

Can someone suggest what am I doing wrong.

Comment: I don't think you can spoof other mail addresses with Gmail, otherwise they would be blacklisted soon. What you can do is, add another email account to your Gmail and then you can send with this mail address (over that outgoing server).

Comment: @DanLee I do believe he did that from his statement "but the email address is registered at gmail.com."... ;)

Comment: Dan Lee Its registered with gmail, so can you suggest what can be done in this case

Comment: "registered with gmail" - so are you talking about google Apps ?

Comment: @sahilagarwal I am sorry I read to fast. Which version of PHPMailer do you use? Is there a method called `SetFrom`?

Answer (score 0):

Try use host:

```
$host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should register the application who sends the mail in your gmail account:

1. Start session in your browser in the gmail account.
2. In the same browser with the session opened, go to https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
3. Send a mail executing your php in the desired server you want to enable.